# Can't seem to figure out how to ignore left and right most array elements in loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, format, output

I'm trying to fill an array made by the user (between size 3-11 odd) with characters in certain element position to get patterns. What the user inputs acts as both the number of rows and columns so If they put in a 5 like in my example below, they'd get a 5 by 5 array. I'm trying to get this pattern

```
-----------
 * * * * *
   * * * 
     *  


-----------  

-----------
 * * * * *
 * * * * *
 * * * * *


-----------
```

Here's the code

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

    int dimension = findDimension();
    char [] [] array2d = new char [dimension] [dimension];

    char star = '*';

    array2d = pointDown(star,dimension);
    System.out.println();
    print(array2d);
}

public static void print(char [] [] arrayParam) {
    for (int hyphen = 0; hyphen < (arrayParam.length*2)+1; hyphen++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }

    System.out.println();
    for(char[] row : arrayParam)
    {
        for(char c : row)
            System.out.print(" " + c);
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }

    for (int hyphen = 0; hyphen < (arrayParam.length*2)+1; hyphen++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
}
```

The problem should be in this method, the loop after this one I think

```
public static char [] [] pointDown (char starParam, int dimenParam) {
    char [] [] pointDown = new char [dimenParam] [dimenParam];

    for (int i = 0; i < dimenParam; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < dimenParam; j++) {
            pointDown[i][j] = ' ';
// I fill the positions first with blank spaces then add the characters
// with the loop below
        }
    }

/* Problem should be in this loop, Is there even a pattern to it though
 * since columns would have to account for both the last and beginning
 * columns after the first loop? Should I make variables for those or is
 */ there a simpler way to do it that I'm missing? 

    for (int i = 0; i <= dimenParam/2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dimenParam; j++) {
            pointDown[i][j] = starParam;
        }
    }

    return pointDown;
}
```

Comment: On the second row, when `i = 1`, you want to skip 1 from the left and 1 from the right. Similarly, on the third row, when `i = 2`, you want to skip 2 from the left and 2 from the right. See a pattern there? So since you want to skip, the `j` loop needed adjusting.

Comment: I’m not going to do your homework for you, but to guide you: Create a method that prints a single line given the parameters length and rank (rank counts up from zero to n). Get that working, with test code, then call that n times from a method that loops from 0 to n.

Comment: I see, thank you for the tips. I know that dimenParam is what decides how far the column printing goes and j is the column number so I figured If I were to decrease dimenParam by 1 it would go 1 less from the right. As for the right side I would want to increment j once more I think since then it would start one higher and go one closer right?

Answer (score 0):

Update: After taking into account what I've been told I was able to figure out the issue. Here's what the code should look like

```
char [] [] pointDown = new char [dimenParam] [dimenParam];

    for (int i = 0; i < dimenParam; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < dimenParam; j++) {
            pointDown[i][j] = ' ';
// As before this part fills the array with blank spaces
        }
    }

    int columnEnd = dimenParam; // Set up a variable to hold how far the column goes to
    int j = 0;   
    for (int row = 0; row <= dimenParam/2; row++) {
        for (int column = j; column < columnEnd; column++) {
            pointDown[row][column] = starParam;
        }
        columnEnd--;  // I had to decrease the ending column in the outer loop
        j++;          // Originally I had this in the inner loop for the longest time
                      // By moving it to the outer loop I avoid out of Bounds and runtime errors

    }
    return pointDown;
```

I'm pretty sure I still over complicated things but I'm happy with this code